# Setup open-mpi in environmental module

Tags: linux, openmpi, environment-modules

I have tried to set up open mpi in environmental module.
First of all, when I use this command : module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64 , the error : ModuleCmd_Load.c(213):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'mpi/openmpi-x86_64' occurs.

There is no 'mpi' in module available(see below), and also there is no modulfile related to the mpi in modulefiles directory(/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles). Note that the openmpi is installed in this path : /opt/openmpi/gcc-4.8.5/4.0.4/ .

As I understand, I have to make a modulefile in modulefiles directory. (Is it correct?)
But I have no idea how can I make this modulefile in this directory. How can I make this file?
I think file 'modulefile-git' or file 'modulefile-info' could give some hint for this problem, but I could catch it. I attached the code of modulefile-git below.

I would be very much obliged to you if you would help me.
Thank you!

- I have tried to write 'modulefile' for openmpi
  And I want that 'module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64' command works.

--- modulefile-git ---

```
#%Module1.0#####################################################################
##
## module-cvs modulefile
##
## modulefiles/module-git.  Generated from module-git.in by configure.
##
proc ModulesHelp { } {
        global version

        puts stderr "\tThis module will set up an alias"
        puts stderr "\tfor easy anonymous check-out of this version of the"
        puts stderr "\tenvironment modules package."
        puts stderr "\get-modules       - retrieve modules sources for this version"
        puts stderr "\n\tVersion $version\n"
}

# for Tcl script use only
set      version                3.2.10
set     _version_               [ string map {. -} $version ]

module-whatis   "get this version of the module sources from SourceForge.net"

set-alias get-modules "git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/modules/git modules-$_version_ && cd modules-$_version_ && git checkout modules-$_version_"

if [ module-info mode load ] {
        ModulesHelp
}
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. *Never* put text data such as source code or configuration files into your question as a picture. Always copy and paste it **as text**. It is very important. See also [ask] and [mcve]. Please [edit] your question with the information as text.

Comment: I really sorry. I edited my question with text code.